# Upcoming Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators

Greetings Craft CMS community!

Over 8 long and fascinating years, the Craft CMS Stack Exchange site has grown and matured, finally [graduating from beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/284597) near the end of last year. We have now reached the point where it is time for our **first official moderator election**.

### Would you be interested in running?

Before we can begin an election process, we need to know that enough members of the community are willing to step up and nominate themselves for a moderator position. We have 3 spots to fill, so it's important that there are enough nominees.

Please post an answer below if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Assuming we have enough willing participants, we could schedule the nomination period as early as January 2023.

### Post a response below!

You don't need to include much in the answer below, just let us know that you're interested in running. This is not an official election nomination thread, simply a "pulse check" to see how many people might want to be a moderator.

You can simply post a message saying "I'm interested in running for moderator" if you are interested.

---

**Thanks everyone!** On behalf of the current moderators, it's been a pleasure serving you for so many years.

Comment: What are the responsibilities of a moderator?

Comment: @CraftQuest Great question! Take a look at [this post](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/upcoming-moderator-election-in-january-2023), which is from a different SE site, but does a fantastic job of explaining what the moderator position entails. Let me know if you have any further questions!

Answer (score 5):

I'll throw my hat into the ring for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in running for moderator

Answer (score 0):

Definitely open to run for moderator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in running for moderator. Finally one from Europe

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in Running. Also... isn't Brad Bell already the unofficial moderator? lol

Comment: I've been called worse. :P